# Is there a way to put a customized keras model inside a python class method?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm trying to build a deep neural network in python using a class method. ((The main idea behind it is to try to customize the loss function later on))
I'm trying to use Keras in the function that defines the neural network structure but it doesn't seem to be working.

```py
# create a class to
class PGNN(keras.Sequential):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()

        X = np.concatenate([x,y], axis=1)
        self.X = X
        self.x = X[:,0:1]
        self.y = X[:,1:2]

    def build_model_u(self):
        model_u = models.Sequential
        model_u.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh', input_shape= 1000))
        model_u.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
        model_u.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='tanh'))
        model_u.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='tanh'))
        model_u.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='tanh'))
        model_u.add(layers.Dense(1))
        model_u.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])


    def train(self, x_train, y_train):
        model = build_model_u(self)
        model.fit()

    def predict(self, x_test):
        model.predict(x_test)

    def validation(self, x_test, y_test):
        model.evaluate(x_test,y_test, verbose=2)
```

I expected the model to start training when I call model.fit(x_train,y_train) but I always get the error "build_model_u is not defined"

```
model = build_model_u(self)
```

NameError: name 'build_model_u' is not defined

Comment: So you're getting different errors despite using the same code?

Comment: Provide more code!! You didn't show the code you use to call `fit` or `build_model_u`. If it's like this then I guess you call `model = build_model_u` and `model.fit` or something? Then that's the error.

Comment: error message shows you in which line is problem so show this line to us.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code and the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is way. You have to extends your custom model class with keras.Model and overtire call method then you can call fit method from your own custom class.
You can follow the following Keras documentations.
https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/#model-subclassing

Answer (score 2):

You must be calling the method like

```
model = build_model_u
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Call the function like this

```
model = build_model_u()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

and also you can remove the output variable

```
output= model_u.add(layers.Dense(3))
```

and keep it this way

```
model_u.add(layers.Dense(3))
```